# How to resample data in Pandas with discrete data?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am stuck with pandas. My idea is to resample data that are expressed by factors. For example, I have observed two cats named Charles and Valentine. As animals are expressing the behavior for longer times, the observations are made when current behaviour changes. I want to resample to get minute-wise data

```
name;timestamp;activity
Charles;10.10.18 12:31;drinks
Charles;10.10.18 12:51;sleep
Charles;10.10.18 13:01;mouse
Valentine;10.10.18 12:31;drinks
Valentine;10.10.18 12:51;sleep
Valentine;10.10.18 13:01;purr
```

My desired output should look like this:

```
name    timestamp   activity
Charles 10.10.18 12:31  drinks
Charles 10.10.18 12:32  drinks
Charles 10.10.18 12:33  drinks
Charles 10.10.18 12:34  drinks
Charles 10.10.18 12:35  drinks
Charles 10.10.18 12:36  drinks
Charles 10.10.18 12:37  drinks
Charles 10.10.18 12:38  drinks
Charles 10.10.18 12:39  drinks
Charles 10.10.18 12:40  drinks
Charles 10.10.18 12:41  drinks
Charles 10.10.18 12:42  drinks
Charles 10.10.18 12:43  drinks
Charles 10.10.18 12:44  drinks
Charles 10.10.18 12:45  drinks
Charles 10.10.18 12:46  drinks
Charles 10.10.18 12:47  drinks
Charles 10.10.18 12:48  drinks
Charles 10.10.18 12:49  drinks
Charles 10.10.18 12:50  drinks
Charles 10.10.18 12:51  sleeps
Charles 10.10.18 12:52  sleeps
Charles 10.10.18 12:53  sleeps
Charles 10.10.18 12:54  sleeps
Charles 10.10.18 12:55  sleeps
Charles 10.10.18 12:56  sleeps
Charles 10.10.18 12:57  sleeps
Charles 10.10.18 12:58  sleeps
Charles 10.10.18 12:59  sleeps
Charles 10.10.18 13:00  sleeps
Charles 10.10.18 13:01  mouse
Valentine   10.10.18 12:31  drinks
Valentine   10.10.18 12:32  drinks
Valentine   10.10.18 12:33  drinks
Valentine   10.10.18 12:34  drinks
Valentine   10.10.18 12:35  drinks
Valentine   10.10.18 12:36  drinks
Valentine   10.10.18 12:37  drinks
Valentine   10.10.18 12:38  drinks
Valentine   10.10.18 12:39  drinks
Valentine   10.10.18 12:40  drinks
Valentine   10.10.18 12:41  drinks
Valentine   10.10.18 12:42  drinks
Valentine   10.10.18 12:43  drinks
Valentine   10.10.18 12:44  drinks
Valentine   10.10.18 12:45  drinks
Valentine   10.10.18 12:46  drinks
Valentine   10.10.18 12:47  drinks
Valentine   10.10.18 12:48  drinks
Valentine   10.10.18 12:49  drinks
Valentine   10.10.18 12:50  drinks
Valentine   10.10.18 12:51  sleeps
Valentine   10.10.18 12:52  sleeps
Valentine   10.10.18 12:53  sleeps
Valentine   10.10.18 12:54  sleeps
Valentine   10.10.18 12:55  sleeps
Valentine   10.10.18 12:56  sleeps
Valentine   10.10.18 12:57  sleeps
Valentine   10.10.18 12:58  sleeps
Valentine   10.10.18 12:59  sleeps
Valentine   10.10.18 13:00  sleeps
Valentine   10.10.18 13:01  purr
```

Using

```
data.resample('60S').pad()
```

didn't work as Pandas states that timestamps are not unique.

Subsetting data for one cat per time didn't help much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are definitely on the right track with `pad`. The only things to notice are the following:

- In order to resample a time series, you need your data frame index to consist of the times to be resampled.
- Whenever you need to split up the data so that each name is treated differently, `groupby` is your friend.
- When performing an action on a group, the resulting time series has as (part of) its index the column used for grouping, so some combination of `reset_index`, `set_index`, `unstack`, and `stack` can typically be used to massage the result into its desired form (but if you don't mind the output being slightly different from your desired output, chances are you can skip this part).

As such, you could let

```
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])
df.set_index('timestamp').groupby('name').resample('T').pad().activity.reset_index()
```

In practice:

```
In [54]: df

Out[54]:
        name           timestamp activity
0    Charles 2018-10-10 12:31:00   drinks
1    Charles 2018-10-10 12:51:00    sleep
2    Charles 2018-10-10 13:01:00    mouse
3  Valentine 2018-10-10 12:31:00   drinks
4  Valentine 2018-10-10 12:51:00    sleep
5  Valentine 2018-10-10 13:01:00     purr

In [91]: df.set_index('timestamp').groupby('name').resample('T').pad().activity.reset_index().head()
Out[91]:
      name           timestamp activity
0  Charles 2018-10-10 12:31:00   drinks
1  Charles 2018-10-10 12:32:00   drinks
2  Charles 2018-10-10 12:33:00   drinks
3  Charles 2018-10-10 12:34:00   drinks
4  Charles 2018-10-10 12:35:00   drinks
```